# Is there a way to invoke JavaScript function, by calling element outside of form via script

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to call a simple function when a value is selected on the form. Problem is that I don't have access to the code where I can set the function directly on the field.

If I were to have access I would simply write `onChange` event directly inside the `<Select>` element. Is there any way to call `<Select>` element inside the script and apply the `onChange` event there?

Here is the my script currently. I am trying to take two values from separate `<Select>` fields and apply their sum to another field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function changeQty ()
{
    var productName = MainForm.elements["ProductCode"].value;
    var Quantity1 = MainForm.elements["SELECT___"+productName+"___23"].value;
    var Quantity2 = MainForm.elements["SELECT___"+productName+"___24"].value;
    
    var QtyUpdated = Quantity1 + Quantity2;
    
    MainForm.elements["QTY."+productName].value = QtyUpdated;
    
}
</script>
```

And here is the form element where I want the function to fire. I only have access to the header where script can be inserted, but not to elements on the page. Also form already has some other JavaScript. Can I have two `onChange` events?

```
<SELECT name="SELECT___1-DAY-ACUVUE___21" onChange="change_option('SELECT___1-DAY-ACUVUE___21',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<OPTION value="192" >-12.00</OPTION>

<OPTION value="193" >-11.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="73" >-11.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="79" >-10.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="80" >-10.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="81" >-9.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="82" >-9.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="83" >-8.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="84" >-8.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="85" >-7.50</OPTION>

<OPTION value="86" >-7.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="87" >-6.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="88" >-6.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="89" >-5.75</OPTION>
<OPTION value="90" >-5.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="91" >-5.25</OPTION>
<OPTION value="92" >-5.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="93" >-4.75</OPTION>
<OPTION value="94" >-4.50</OPTION>

<OPTION value="95" >-4.25</OPTION>
<OPTION value="96" >-4.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="97" >-3.75</OPTION>
<OPTION value="98" >-3.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="99" >-3.25</OPTION>
<OPTION value="100" >-3.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="101" >-2.75</OPTION>
<OPTION value="102" >-2.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="103" >-2.25</OPTION>

<OPTION value="104" >-2.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="105" >-1.75</OPTION>
<OPTION value="106" >-1.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="107" >-1.25</OPTION>
<OPTION value="108" >-1.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="109" >-0.75</OPTION>
<OPTION value="110" >-0.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="112" >+0.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="113" >+0.75</OPTION>

<OPTION value="114" >+1.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="115" >+1.25</OPTION>
<OPTION value="116" >+1.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="117" >+1.75</OPTION>
<OPTION value="118" >+2.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="119" >+2.25</OPTION>
<OPTION value="120" >+2.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="121" >+2.75</OPTION>
<OPTION value="122" >+3.00</OPTION>

<OPTION value="123" >+3.25</OPTION>
<OPTION value="124" >+3.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="125" >+3.75</OPTION>
<OPTION value="126" >+4.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="127" >+4.25</OPTION>
<OPTION value="128" >+4.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="129" >+4.75</OPTION>
<OPTION value="130" >+5.00</OPTION>
<OPTION value="131" >+5.25</OPTION>

<OPTION value="132" >+5.50</OPTION>
<OPTION value="133" >+5.75</OPTION>
<OPTION value="134" >+6.00</OPTION>
</SELECT>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the element you are interested in have an id or name field set. I solved this very problem yesterday for a form on my site. You can use jquery to accomplish this easily.

Add the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id_cities_0").change(function(){
    //call your function here
  }); 
})
```

Replace id_cities_0 with the id of your element which you can find by viewing source. Make sure the id does not change though.

If the element doesn't have an id, write back.

Comment: Hi, no my element doesn't have Id, just name: <SELECT name="SELECT___1-DAY-ACUVUE___21" onChange="change_option('SELECT___1-DAY-ACUVUE___21',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">

Comment: try using this as a selector instead of the $("#id_cities_0") $("input[name=<<name of your input field>>]").

Comment: Thanks. I am a complete rookie in this. Do I need to reference particular jQuery library in <script src=??>

Comment: so script should look something like this:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name=SELECT___"+productName+"___23]").change(function(){
    
 function changeQty ()
{
 var productName = MainForm.elements["ProductCode"].value;
 var Quantity1 = MainForm.elements["SELECT___"+productName+"___23"].value;
 var Quantity2 = MainForm.elements["SELECT___"+productName+"___24"].value;
 
 var QtyUpdated = Quantity1 + Quantity2;
 
 MainForm.elements["QTY."+productName].value = QtyUpdated;
 
}
  }); 
})


</script>

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do without other library dependancy.  First your questions...

**Q**: Can I have two onChange events.
**A**: Yes, if you register with addEventListener/attachEvent see [quirksmode primer](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) on events.  You can have >1 of any kind of event.

To attach an event to something on the page after it's loaded:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load',prep,false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload',prep);
}
```

Where `prep` would be a function that attaches your `changeQty` function to whatever elements you need in the page:

```
function prep() {
    /* Assuming your MainForm.elements process gets an element*/
    var el=MainForm.elements["SELECT___"+productName+"___23"];
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener('change',changeQty,false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent('onchange',changeQty);
    }
}
```

`onload`/`load` will wait until the entire DOM has loaded, that is scripts/css/HTML and graphics.  Just a warning - if the page-load is complex it may not work as soon as the page renders.  If you can control content at the end of the HTML (before `</html>`) then you can get around this with the following (instead of attaching `prep` to `load` and defining `prep` function):

```
<script>
(function() { 
    /* Assuming your MainForm.elements process gets an element*/
    var el=MainForm.elements["SELECT___"+productName+"___23"];
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener('change',changeQty,false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent('onchange',changeQty);
    }
}());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```